# AWS LAMP permissions issue with HTML & KML

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kml, lamp

I am running a LAMP server on EC2

I am attempting to load a google map with a KML file overlay

As part of this, I am hosting the kml file in the same place as the html page - /var/www/html

However, after using SCP to successfully transfer the kml file, I am having some issues

The html page is not showing the KML overlay. On inspection, when I directly go to where the KML is hosted - I get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /TfL_Stations.kml on this server.
```

How do I change the permissions for this kml file to allow it to be called by the Javascript within the HTML code in the index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked this out -

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/TfL_Stations.kml
```